# Stopping a Particular Android Activity

Tags: android

I have one main activity like

`public class mainActivity extends sampleActivity`

using sampleActivity get camera now i want to stop camera when 5 photo are captured and display message.i am put condition and message and all but i can't get solution for stop only **sampleActivity** in mainActivity.

```
public class mainActivity extends sampleActivity {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    private void count()
        {
            try
            {
                count=0;
                String str="SELECT count(*) as count FROM test";
                mCursor=mDatabase.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(str,null);
                    mCursor.moveToFirst();
                count=mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("count"));

                if(count>=3){

                    //sampleActivity.finish();  here i want to finish sampleactivity

                    Toast.makeText(sampleActivity .this,"close!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

Comment: just add finish(); in the block of sampleActivity.

Comment: Post your whole code. you get correct answers instead of answers only on guesses.

Comment: best option is to open the camera by invoking service and stop the service to close camera

Comment: @user1722880 try my answer hope this works.

Comment: @user1722880 you try my answer?

Comment: yes try your answer but it finish mainActivity and i want to finish sampleActivity

Answer (score 1):

Use `YOUR_ACTIVITY.finish()` to stop your activity.

Comment: sampleActivity.finish() its not working.. it display error can't get .finish() after sampleActivity

Comment: Post your complete code, then it will be possible to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in both `mainActivity` class and `sampleActivity` class-

```
@Override 
public void finish() { 
super.finish(); 
}
```

And in `mainActivity` class just call `finish();` when you want to finish `sampleActivity.`

Answer (score 0):

You should put your camera operation code into a method in base class and `override` this in your derived class with simple `Toast` alert.
After you should make a call of `super` class function first 5 times and after call derived class function 6th onward, that it.

Comment: i do all things put condition and toast message now i just want to close sampleActivity after condition..